Unable to open LibreOffice Base 22.04
I downloaded LibreOffice Base version 22.04.5 but when I double-clicked on its icon it did not open. Please what should I do?

Open a terminal. Run the command soffice --base. If you get an error, copy and paste the complete terminal output into your question above.

Just for clarity 22.04.5 is the version of the Ubuntu OS not the version of Libre Office.
